# Converting Matlab gaussian derivatives to Opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, gaussian, derivative

I trying to convert an old exercise i made in matlab to OpenCV. Code is posted below. I havent been able to find any functions in OpenCv that does what i want, might be because of other names then what i expect.

Here are the outputs when taken the max response in each location as label. Clearly somethings wronge.

[image: my opencv output]
[image: Matlab output]

Here is the matlab code:

```
function responses = getBifResponsesEx(im, myEps, sigma, kernelSize)

    if ( nargin == 3 )
        if ( sigma >= 1 )
            kernelSize = 6*sigma + 1;
        else
            kernelSize = 7;
        end        
    end

    responses = zeros(size(im,1), size(im,2), 7);

    %
    % Gaussian derivatives    
    %
    kernVal = ceil(kernelSize/2) - 1;
    x = (-kernVal:kernVal);
    g = 1/(2*pi*sigma^2)*exp(-(x.^2./(2*(sigma^2))));
    g = g/sum(g);
    dg = -2*x/(2*sigma^2).*g*sigma;
    ddg = ((2*x/(2*sigma^2)).^2 - 1/(sigma^2)).*g*sigma;

    %
    % Gaussian convolution of the image
    %
    s00 = filter2(g, im);
    s00 = filter2(g', s00);

    s10 = filter2(g', im);
    s10 = filter2(dg, s10);

    s01 = filter2(g, im);
    s01 = filter2(dg', s01);

    s11 = filter2(dg, im);
    s11 = filter2(dg', s11);

    s20 = filter2(g', im);
    s20 = filter2(g', s20);
    s20 = filter2(ddg, s20);

    s02 = filter2(g, im);
    s02 = filter2(g, s02);
    s02 = filter2(ddg', s02);    

    %
    % Symmetry types - MISSING CODE!!!!
    %
    lam = sigma^2*(s20+s02);
    gam = sigma^2*(sqrt((s20-s02).^2+4*s11.^2));

    responses(:,:,1) = myEps*s00;
    responses(:,:,2) = 2*sigma*sqrt(s10.^2+s01.^2);
    responses(:,:,3) = +lam;
    responses(:,:,4) = -lam;
    responses(:,:,5) = 2^-.5*(gam+lam);
    responses(:,:,6) = 2^-.5*(gam-lam);
    responses(:,:,7) = gam;


end
```

And here is my converted page. From what i can see, it goes wronge with the s20,s02 responses. Anyone able to tell me what to do?

```
void extract_bif_features(const cv::Mat & src,
        std::vector<cv::Mat> & dst, BIFParams params)
    {

        float sigma = params.sigma;
        float n=0;

        int kernelSize;
        if(sigma>=1)
            kernelSize = 6*sigma + 1;
        else
            kernelSize = 7;



        cv::Mat gray,p00,p10,p01,p11,p20,p02;
        cv::cvtColor(src,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);


        auto kernVal = (int)ceil(kernelSize/2.0) - 1;
        cv::Mat_<float> g(1,kernelSize);float*gp = g.ptr<float>();
        cv::Mat_<float> dg(1,kernelSize);float*dgp = dg.ptr<float>();   
        cv::Mat_<float> ddg(1,kernelSize);  float*ddgp = ddg.ptr<float>();
        cv::Mat_<float> X(1,kernelSize);float*xp = X.ptr<float>();
        auto gsum=0.0f;
        for(int x = -kernVal;x<=kernVal;++x)
        {
            xp[x+kernVal] = x;
            gp[x+kernVal] = 1/(2*CV_PI*sigma*sigma)*exp(-(x*x/(2*(sigma*sigma))));
            gsum +=  gp[x+kernVal];
        }

        g = g/gsum;


        cv::multiply((-2*X / (2*sigma*sigma)),g*sigma,dg);

        cv::pow((2*X/(2*sigma*sigma)),2,ddg);
        ddg -=1/(sigma*sigma);
        cv::multiply(ddg,g*sigma,ddg);
        std::cout << ddg<< std::endl;
        std::cout << dg<< std::endl;





        cv::sepFilter2D(gray,p00,CV_32FC1,g,g,cv::Point(-1,-1),0.0,cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);       cv::sepFilter2D(gray,p01,CV_32FC1,dg,g,cv::Point(-1,-1),0.0,cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);      cv::sepFilter2D(gray,p10,CV_32FC1,g,dg,cv::Point(-1,-1),0.0,cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);      cv::sepFilter2D(gray,p11,CV_32FC1,dg,dg,cv::Point(-1,-1),0.0,cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);     

//NOT SURE HERE
cv::sepFilter2D(gray,p20,CV_32FC1,g,ddg,cv::Point(-1,-1),0.0,cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
//cv::sepFilter2D(p20,p20,CV_32FC1,1,g,cv::Point(-1,-1),0.0,cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);      cv::sepFilter2D(gray,p02,CV_32FC1,g,ddg,cv::Point(-1,-1),0.0,cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);     //cv::sepFilter2D(p02,p02,CV_32FC1,g,1,cv::Point(-1,-1),0.0,cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);      
cv::filter2D(gray,p20,CV_32FC1,g,cv::Point(-1,-1),0.0,cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
cv::filter2D(p20,p20,CV_32FC1,g,cv::Point(-1,-1),0.0,cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
cv::filter2D(p20,p20,CV_32FC1,ddg,cv::Point(-1,-1),0.0,cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
cv::filter2D(gray,p02,CV_32FC1,g,cv::Point(-1,-1),0.0,cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
cv::filter2D(p02,p02,CV_32FC1,g.t(),cv::Point(-1,-1),0.0,cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
cv::filter2D(p02,p02,CV_32FC1,ddg.t(),cv::Point(-1,-1),0.0,cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);




        dst.resize(6);
        auto sigma_square = sigma*sigma;

        cv::Mat Lam = sigma_square * (p20+p02);
        cv::Mat Gam ;
        cv::sqrt((((p20-p02)*(p20-p02))+4*p11*p11),Gam);
        Gam *= sigma_square ;

        cv::Mat test = p10*p10;
        //slop
        cv::sqrt(p10*p10 + p01*p01,dst[0]);
        dst[0] = dst[0]*2*sigma;//slop
        //blob 
        dst[1] = Lam;
        dst[2] = -1*Lam;
        //line
        dst[3] = sqrt(2.0f)*(Gam+Lam);
        dst[4] = sqrt(2.0f)*(Gam-Lam);
        //saddle
        dst[5] = Gam;


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is from what i get sofar.

cv::multiply((p20-p02),(p20-p02),Gam); is not the same as Gam = (p20-p02)*(p20-p02);

Full Code: Classify according to higest response, Griffin(2008).

```
RIDAR_API void extract_bif_features(const cv::Mat & src,
    std::vector<cv::Mat> & dst, BIFParams params)
{

    float sigma = params.sigma;
    float eta = params.eta;

    int kernelSize;
    if(sigma>=1)
        kernelSize = 4*sigma + 1;
    else
        kernelSize = 5;

    auto kernVal = (int)ceil(kernelSize/2.0) - 1;
    cv::Mat_<float> g(1,kernelSize);float*gp = g.ptr<float>();
    cv::Mat_<float> X(1,kernelSize);float*xp = X.ptr<float>();

    auto gsum=0.0f;
    for(int x = -kernVal;x<=kernVal;++x)
    {
        xp[x+kernVal] = x;
        gp[x+kernVal] = 1/(2*CV_PI*sigma*sigma)*exp(-(x*x/(2*(sigma*sigma))));
        gsum +=  gp[x+kernVal];
    } g = g/gsum;

    cv::Mat dg = -2*X.mul(g*sigma) / (2*sigma*sigma);
    cv::Mat ddg = ((2*X/(2*sigma*sigma)).mul((2*X/(2*sigma*sigma))) - 1/(sigma*sigma)).mul(g*sigma);



    cv::Mat gray,p00,p10,p01,p11,p20,p02;
    cv::cvtColor(src,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::filter2D(gray,p00,CV_32FC1,g);
    cv::filter2D(p00,p00,CV_32FC1,g.t());

    cv::filter2D(gray,p10,CV_32FC1,g.t());
    cv::filter2D(p10,p10,CV_32FC1,dg);

    cv::filter2D(gray,p01,CV_32FC1,g);
    cv::filter2D(p01,p01,CV_32FC1,dg.t());

    cv::filter2D(gray,p11,CV_32FC1,dg);
    cv::filter2D(p11,p11,CV_32FC1,dg.t());

    cv::filter2D(gray,p20,CV_32FC1,g.t());
    cv::filter2D(p20,p20,CV_32FC1,g.t());
    cv::filter2D(p20,p20,CV_32FC1,ddg);

    cv::filter2D(gray,p02,CV_32FC1,g);
    cv::filter2D(p02,p02,CV_32FC1,g);
    cv::filter2D(p02,p02,CV_32FC1,ddg.t());


#ifdef DISPLAY_WHILE_RUNNING
    double max,min;
    cv::imshow("p00",p00/255);
    //
    cv::minMaxIdx(p01,&min,&max);
    cv::imshow("p01",(p01-min)/(max-min));
    //
    cv::minMaxIdx(p10,&min,&max);
    cv::imshow("p10",(p10-min)/(max-min));

    cv::minMaxIdx(p11,&min,&max);
    cv::imshow("p11",(p11-min)/(max-min));

    cv::minMaxIdx(p02,&min,&max);
    cv::imshow("p02",(p02-min)/(max-min));

    cv::minMaxIdx(p20,&min,&max);
    cv::imshow("p20",(p20-min)/(max-min));
    cv::waitKey();
#endif  


    dst.resize(7);
    auto sigma_square = sigma*sigma;
    auto p2d = p20-p02;

    //LAM
    dst[2] = sigma_square * (p20+p02);
    //GAM
    cv::sqrt( (p2d).mul(p2d) + (4.0f * p11.mul(p11)) ,dst[6] );
    dst[6] = dst[6] * sigma_square;

    //FLAT
    dst[0] = eta*p00;

    //slop
    cv::sqrt(p10.mul(p10)+p01.mul(p01),dst[1]); 
    dst[1] *= 2.0f*sigma;

    //blob dst[2]   
    dst[3] = -dst[2];

    //line
    dst[4] = pow(2.0,-0.5)*(dst[6]+dst[2]);
    dst[5] = pow(2.0,-0.5)*(dst[6]-dst[2]);

    //saddle dst[6] 

#ifdef DISPLAY_WHILE_RUNNING        
    double max,min;
    cv::minMaxIdx(dst[0],&min,&max);//
    cv::imshow("FLAT",(dst[0]-min)/(max-min));

    cv::minMaxIdx(dst[1],&min,&max);//
    cv::imshow("SLOPE",(dst[1]-min)/(max-min));

    cv::minMaxIdx(dst[2],&min,&max);
    cv::imshow("BLOB+",(dst[2]-min)/(max-min));

    cv::minMaxIdx(dst[3],&min,&max);//
    cv::imshow("BLOB-",(dst[3]-min)/(max-min));

    cv::minMaxIdx(dst[4],&min,&max);//
    cv::imshow("LINE+",(dst[4]-min)/(max-min));

    cv::minMaxIdx(dst[5],&min,&max);
    cv::imshow("LINE-",(dst[5]-min)/(max-min));

    cv::minMaxIdx(dst[6],&min,&max);
    cv::imshow("SADDLE",(dst[6]-min)/(max-min));

    cv::waitKey();
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you take average on dg and ddg?

```
cv::filter2D(gray,p20,CV_32FC1,g.t());



cv::filter2D(p20,p20,CV_32FC1,g.t());
```

why take two times of filter here?

//GAM

cv::sqrt( (p2d).mul(p2d) + (4.0f * p11.mul(p11)) ,dst[6] ); 
dst[6] = dst[6] * sigma_square;
    where you get this formula ?